# How to get ssh key of sha256 fingerprint value?

Tags: linux, macos

I want to know how to print ssh key of sha256 fingerprint of rsa public key.

Comment: You can't, [cryptographic hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) aren't reversible.

Comment: What you mean by crytographic hash function?

Comment: Exactly the same thing as Wikipedia (follow link). The fingerprint you have is the cryptographic hash of the public key.